# Custom MKMarkerAnnotationView Like Photos App

Tags: swift

I am attempting to do a custom pinView like how the Photos app does it:

[image]

So far, most resources I can find on SO or [here](http://sweettutos.com/2016/01/21/swift-mapkit-tutorial-series-how-to-customize-the-map-annotations-callout-request-a-transit-eta-and-launch-the-transit-directions-to-your-destination/) and [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160517/mapkit-tutorial-getting-started) show ways to customise the image of the pin or the callout views, but none on a customised view of the marker itself.

Eventually, what I want to achieve is similar to the Photos app, where each image displayed on the marker itself is a profileImage of the user, but a rounded view. My code so far is very basic:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin") as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
        
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "profileImage"))
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        
        return annotationView
    }
```

I've really exhausted my search online for resources. What can I try next?

Comment: This is done with custom PXPlacesMapThumbnailAnnotationView + renderer from PlacesKit.framework. Basically all manual work. No shortcut.

Comment: @MarekH do you know of any resources on those two frameworks? I can't seem to find resources on PXPlacesMapThumbnailAnnotationView and PlacesKit.

Comment: It's Apple private framework. You can look at it using Hopper app. "/Volumes/Mojave/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"

Answer (score 5):

you can implement any custom design you want, you just need to provide a delegate method called viewFor.

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin", for: annotation)
    pinView = MapPinView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    return pinView
}
```

In viewDidload method set the mapview delegate to self and of course register your custom view like bellow.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   mapView.delegate = self
   mapView.register(MapPinView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "pin")
}
```

And a custom view can look like this.

```swift
import MapKit

class MapPinView: MKAnnotationView {
    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "bg")
        imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageview
    }()
    
    private lazy var bottomCornerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        return view
    }()
    
    // MARK: Initialization
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        containerView.addSubview(bottomCornerView)
        bottomCornerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15.0).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
        bottomCornerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
        
        let angle = (39.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        bottomCornerView.transform = transform
        
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And mine looks like this.
[image]

Comment: does this solution allow clustering of the pins? it seemed part of the question

Comment: yes, you just pass a array of annotations instead of one annotation, that should do the job.

Comment: Works very nicely!

Comment: Just a note after implementing your solution. You can make it better by using the `MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier` when registering your class and then also `MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier` for clustering. In viewFor: just return you custom annotation view with those default identifiers